# does the volume of a ball remain constant under deformation?

Tags: geometry, optimization

I'm a psychology student and was reading Piaget, he says that the volume of a sphere (ball of clay) remains constant if we deform the sphere into a roll for example, If you take the limit case of the roll its volume goes to zero as one of its dimensions goes to zero, I mean, its length increases but the diameter decrases. Using the intermediate value theorem could I say that when the sphere is deformed its volume is not conserved?. I am not a mathematics student, I guess I should say it is continue uosly deformed and add some more information, I did the best I could.

Comment: I would say any answer to the question "when the sphere is deformed its volume is not conserved?" would require that this deformation actually be made precise.  Theoretically, you could compress the clay as much as you like, so its volume would not stay constant.  But for general squeezing (and this is a very imprecise notion!) it will stay the same.  Perhaps *Cavilieri's Principle* might be an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, the volume is $V$ and the roll is a cylinder of height $h$ and radius $r$. Then 
$\pi r^2h=V $
hence $h = V/(\pi r^2)$. As the radius $r$ approaches $0$, the height $h$ grows indefinitely. One expresses this as
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} V/(\pi r^2) = \infty
$$
The volume does remain constant in the process.

The apparent contradiction arises when you imagine that $r$ actually *becomes* $0$ in the process, and then conclude that the volume suddenly drops from $V$ to $0$. But $r$ never becomes $0$ in reality. It can be arbitrarily small, but not zero.

To speculate about the volume of a "cylinder" with zero radius and infinite height is about as productive as to debate what would happen if an unstoppable object collided with an immovable one.

Comment: Now you got me wondering...

Answer (score 0):

I shall answer this question to myself five years ago:
It depends on what transformations you are considering, if you are defining volume preserving transformations then the volume will be preserved (I tell you now that I know it is symplectic geometry what studies those transformations that you thought were a huge theorem for one of Piaget's children to naturally realize). Although you were intuitively thinking about something called a homotopy from the ball, to the cylinder to the line segment and there volume is not preserved. The interplay of topological transformations and geometrical transformations of a space is probably the most beautiful thing I have seen. This is proof for the power of curiosity.